# Is God's Light beyond time?

Tags: light

Why are photons able to do the same thing as God in terms of not experiencing time atleast from the photon's own frame of reference, where it doesn't experience time. Of course from the outside, they are restricted to moving at speed of light "c", but from its own frame of reference, the photon's creation and destruction happen at the exact same spot, and for a photon at the surface of the sun, the instant it is created from the electron accelerating with respect to the proton, is the same instant it is destroyed when it is absorbed by the electron in the orbital of a proton on the Nitrogen atom on the upper atmosphere of Earth. So does this mean that light is also beyond time like God, and was there some light before creation being released by God from his goodness instead of the accelerating charges due to electromagnetic field. What about gravitational waves and gluons which do the same thing, and are all massless particles in their own frame of reference in Heaven, because they are outside of time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on SE-Physics.

Comment: I edited, so now I am talking about God's light.